# Is there any possibility to automate Siebel( High Interactivity framework) application using QTP or selenium

Tags: oracle, object, selenium, qtp, siebel

I want to automate Siebel application which is having Siebel HI framework .I tried using qtp and selenium,but the problem is objects ,tables are not recognizable .
Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1):

The Siebel STA module is a separately licensed module, as can be seen in the Bookshelf link provided by Motti. Though most Siebel projects have this included, some don't. Please check and confirm that your project is running with this module included: [Siebel Test Automation Interfaces](http://www.oracle.com/us/support/licensecodes/siebel/index.html).

If you are doing a PoC and want to verify that it works, then Oracle provides the temporary license codes from the same URL.

In Siebel High Interactive (as opposed to Open UI) the HTML interface is a large number of nested iFrames. Although a very diligent Selenium person may be able to automate some scenario's, this is not the best approach for HI. For HI QTP/UFT and serveral other test automation vendors will be able to help you with this.

In case you have the opportunity to run Open UI, then my advice would be to investigate Selenium once more, as the Open UI HTML interface is a single DOM object and makes this much easier.

Comment: We have done some server side configuration s.now uft is recognizing siebel objects

Answer (score 0):

UFT supports Siebel HI via it's [STA](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14004_01/books/TestGuide/TestGuide_AutoFuncTest5.html) framework so the requirements for testing Siebel HI with UFT are:

- Install and activate UFT's Siebel add-in on the testing machine
- Install STA on the Siebel server
- Access the Siebel application via the automation URL

  - (http://hostname/callcenter/start.swe?**SWECmd=AutoOn**)

Comment: The STA process should be running in task manager if you use the correct URL regardless of whether UFT is involved. It's also possible to configure a password so that adding _SWECmd=AutoOn_ may not be enough (an additional **AutoToken** parameter).

Comment: First of all STA should run in Task manager.without running uft will not recognize the objects eventhough SWECmd=AutoOn is appended to url.

Comment: ...After appending ?Swe=AutoOn to url also STA is not running in task manager.

Comment: @sajju _Swe_ or _SWECmd_? I would suggest talking to your Siebel administrator to see if activated and if there's a need for _AutoToken_.